# User Interface for C-code

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, language-agnostic

I've written a code in linux OS which produces prog.out as output file.
Now I've to write GUI for the code.

what are best ways to write it?

PS - I wanted to choose between Java Swings and openGL.
Which is best for writing a simple GUI and integrating it with my C- Application

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Anjuta...
http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL is a rendering library, not a UI toolkit. Comparing it to Swing doesn't make sense. And you can't choose Swing for a C application, unless you'd rather do the UI in Java and interact with a C "backend".

For a pure C solution, the best choice would probably be the [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to use another language (you mention Java) then you may find C++ and Qt to be a good fit.  Linking to the existing C code will be trivial and Qt works well on a great many platforms should you ever wish to support other platforms in addition to Linux.